# high procesion position in 3D when using processing

Tags: 3d, processing

Processing offer 3D features when using P3D or OPENGL argument in the size function,in 2D scenes.we can get an exactly postion with mouseX and mouseY,but in 3D,how can I get the mouse？

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get, say, `mouseZ` since `mouseX` and `mouseY` tell you where your mouse is on the window, which is 2D by nature.

However, there is something called 3D picking which is what you are looking for. It is a very simple process:

> The ability to match a mouse click on a window showing a 3D scene to
>   the primitive (let's assume a triangle) who was fortunate enough to be
>   projected to the exact same pixel where the mouse hit is called 3D
>   Picking.

You can read detailed explanations and implementation tutorials on it here: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial29/tutorial29.html and http://schabby.de/picking-opengl-ray-tracing/ (done with OpenGL).

There is, incidentally, a Picking library for Processing 2+ that you can get here: https://github.com/nclavaud/picking This library comes with two examples to help you see how its implemented.

To get better search results on this, use `3D picking` as your search term and you'll get a lot of results on Google.